# Changing a variable attribute into the variable name

Tags: r

I have an SPSS file that I uploaded into R and I want the label attribute to become the actual variable name across the dataframe. What function can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `haven` to read in the file, you can use `labelled::var_label()`:

```
library(haven)
library(labelled)

mydata <- read_sav("filename.sav")

# `var_label()` returns a list - need to coerce to character vector to assign
names(mydata) <- as.character(var_label(mydata))
```